# MySQL PDO statement returnin \n after each var

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table which has two columns. player & subbedOnFor. Both columns can contain the ID of player, I need to count the total number of times each player appears in both columns combined. its also helpfull if i can get the total number of times each user appears per column as well, so a result may look something like the followin.

```
Player 1
TotalApps = 4
player = 3
subbedOnFor = 1
```

This is my SQL statement

```
$limit = 5;
    $query = 'select player, game, count(*) AS totalApps, sum(first) AS starter, sum(second) AS sub
              from ((select game as game, player as player, 1 as first, 0 as second from appearances) union all (select game as game, subbedOnFor as subbedOnFor, 0, 1 from appearances)) myApps
              JOIN players ON myApps.player = players.playerid
              JOIN games ON myApps.game = games.gameid
              WHERE games.date >= :start AND games.date <= :end
              group by player  
              ORDER BY totalApps DESC
              LIMIT :limit';

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':start', $seasonStart);
    $stmt->bindValue(':end', $seasonEnd);
    $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    if($stmt->execute()){
        
            while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
            
                $data[] = $row;
                print_r($row);
            }
        
        return $data;
    }
```

My issue is though, the data i am getting back from this PDO statement has \n after every single returned value.

```
"stdClass Object\n(\n    [player] => 0\n    [game] => 53\n    [totalApps] => 3\n    [starter] => 0\n    [sub] => 3\n)\nstdClass Object\n(\n    [player] => 1\n    [game] => 53\n    [totalApps] => 2\n    [starter] => 1\n    [sub] => 1\n)\nstdClass Object\n(\n    [player] => 32\n    [game] => 53\n    [totalApps] => 1\n    [starter] => 1\n    [sub] => 0\n)\nstdClass Object\n(\n    [player] => 24\n    [game] => 53\n    [totalApps] => 1\n    [starter] => 1\n    [sub] => 0\n)\nstdClass Object\n(\n    [player] => 14\n    [game] => 53\n
```

Anyone any idea where all of these \n are coming from? I think its something to do with my SQL code, because the format of the PDO statements i have used multiple times in other places with no issue.

Further addition, when this is passed back to a jQuery $.ajax statement, the alerted output looks like the following.

```
[{\"player\":\"0\",\"game\":\"53\",\"totalApps\":\"3\",\"starter\":\"0\",\"sub\":\"3\"},{\"player\":\"1\",\"game\":\"53\",\"totalApps\":\"2\",\"starter\":\"1\",\"sub\":\"1\"},{\"player\":\"32\",\"game\":\"53\",\"totalApps\":\"1\",\"starter\":\"1\",\"sub\":\"0\"},{\"player\":\"24\",\"game\":\"53\",\"totalApps\":\"1\",\"starter\":\"1\",\"sub\":\"0\"},{\"player\":\"14\",\"game\":\"53\",\"totalApps\":\"1\",\"starter\":\"1\",\"sub\":\"0\"}]"
```

the many \\ i dont get when using the exact same pdo setup with more "basic" my sql statements, i have only had this issue (I think!) since trying to use the SELECT in the FROM statement.

Comment: How exactly are you obtaining this output?

Comment: You're fetching objects, and then you're calling `print_r()` to print them. That's what you get when you print an object.

Comment: The example give here was a Print_r of $row from my PDO statement.

Comment: The `\n` come from the fact that `print_r()` puts each property on a separate line of output.

Comment: It's intended to show the object in a nicely formatted fashion.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for answering, i have those (i think!) even without the print_r, because i pass them to an API pipeline, and then back to a jQuery $.ajax call, if i alert() the results out there, i still get all of the backspaces, which i havent had in any of my other sql statements when passed through the same process

Comment: `print_r()`  is intended for displaying data to a human programmer when debugging, not for computer consumption in an API.

Comment: Use JSON to format the data in a way that JavaScript can parse it.

Comment: Those can't be produced by the database. The DB has nothing to do with output, it just provides data. Now, normally, your browser would interpret those `\n`s as new lines. That's why I was asking how you obtain the output - where are you observing this string?

Comment: Thanks @El_Vanja so i am currently using print_r to display it on my screen, that is what i am getting. the reason i think its something to do with the sql is because if i change the sql statement to something more basic, like a SELECT * from a single table, i dont get this issue, i pass it to my jQuery as JSON which is parsed no bother with my JS. However, as soon as i changed to the above SQL, it could no longer parse.

Comment: Remove the `print_r` from there and try. If the problem still persists, check that you haven't accidentally left another debugging line somewhere.

Comment: I did this, I also cut the code out, closed the my editor and reopen and pasted it back in, saved, and this seems to have sorted the issue!? thanks all for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I took the advice of removing the print_r that i was using to display the ocde, and that combined with restarting by editor and copy and pasting the SQL back in seems to have resolved the issue, still not 100% sure why the JS wasnt parsong the JSON, but no longer a problem.